# How to notify iframe in the parent window that all the scripts of yandex map has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps

There is a cross-window iframe, which contains a link to index.php from another server, which, in turn, has a Yandex maps api script (see below). How to make sure that this script chain is fully loaded? I'm trying the following way:

```html
 <script>
            function loaded() {
                window.parent.postMessage('loaded', '*');
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=bla-bla-bla&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript" onload="loaded()"></script>
```

The message arrives, but the map is not displayed. Which, in my opinion, means incomplete loading of scripts.

[Chain of yandex map scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFfTW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to `ymaps.ready()`. https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ready-docpage/

```
ymaps.ready(() => notify())
```

Comment: OMG, I was completely sure it won't help and didn't do that. As I used that to get a location, not to ensure that everything has been loaded. Thanks so much for pointing out to it